# Export list of memberof from user.txt

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm a newbie for powershell. Below script working fine I just need to add memberof in this. how can I achieve it?
I want to achieve like this.

```
User    Group 
------  ------
User    Group, Group 1, Group 2 
User1   Group, Group 2 
User2   Group, Group 1 
User3   Group, Group 1, Group 2, Group 3
```

---

```
$USERS = Get-Content c:\Temp\users.txt
$USERS|Foreach{Get-ADUser $_ -Properties * |Select SAMAccountName, mail, XXXXX, memberof}|Export-CSV -Path C:\Temp\USERS.csv
```

Thanks in advance.

Guide me guys.

Comment: what exactly is the problem, seems you have already added memberof

Comment: I want to achieve like this.

User     Group
-------       ---------
User  Group, Group 1, Group 2
User1 Group,  Group 2
User2 Group, Group 1
User2 Group, Group 1, Group 2, Group 3

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're having difficulties in exporting the data to a consistent list. On top of this, the group names are not easily readable, so I added a function for it:

```
Function Get-DisplayName {
    Param (
        [String[]]$CN
    )
    Process {
        foreach ($C in $CN) {
            $m = Get-ADObject -Identity $C -Properties displayName,cn
            if ($m.ObjectClass -eq "user") {$m.displayName} Else{$m.cn} 
        }
    }
}

$Users = Get-Content 'c:\Temp\users.txt'

$Result = $Users | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser $_ -Properties * | Select-Object SAMAccountName, mail, 
        @{Name='Group';Expression={Get-DisplayName $_.memberof}}
}

$Export = Foreach ($R in $Result) {
    Foreach ($G in $R.Group) {
         $R | Select-Object SamAccountName, Mail, @{Name='Group';Expression={$G}}
    }
}

$Export | Export-CSV -Path 'C:\Temp\UsersExport.csv'
```

The output will look like this:

```
SamAccountName    Mail              Group
--------------    ----              -----
Bobs              Bob@domain.com    Group 1
Bobs              Bob@domain.com    Group 2
Bobs              Bob@domain.com    Group 3
Mikec             Mike@domain.com   Group 1
Mikec             Mike@domain.com   Group 2
...
```

The `Select-Object` CmdLet accepts `Expressions`. By using this we can call the function to find the correct `DisplayName`. Later on in the script, we can then just expand this data to have one line per `Group` that the user is member of.

To get you started you can use these commands:

- To find information about a CmdLet you can use `Get-Help Select-Object -ShowWindow`
- To see which CmdLets are available to you, you can use `Get-Command '*Select*'`

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Sorry mate it is not working giving error as below:-
#TYPE System.Collections.Hashtable
"IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Keys","Values","SyncRoot","Count"

Comment: I've tested the code multiple times, works fine. Is your input file only containing SamAccountNames?

Comment: Yes im using SamAccountNames.

Comment: Are you using PowerShell version 3 or 4? You might need to update to be able to use `[PSCustomObject]`

Comment: its 2.0. maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Updated the answer to be compatible with PowerShell version 2.0

Comment: Its working like charm. thank you. can i join the name & group? some users have multiple groups. is it possible? thanks in advance mate.

Comment: I'm sorry, you changed your question. I suggest asking a new one for this.